# How to add a primary key on a bucket in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have created a couchbase cluster with 1 node.
[image: -]

and I have 2 buckets with data in it.

[image: -]

when i'm trying to run a select command in the query section, i am getting this error
[image]

I have tried a few ways to create primary indexes, but none seems to works.

This is the error i get when i try to create a promary key.

```
[
  {
    "code": 5000,
    "msg": "GSI CreatePrimaryIndex() - cause: Index creation for index List2_index, bucket List2, scope _default, collection _default cannot start. Reason: Fails to create index.  There is no available index service that can process this request at this time. Index Service can be in bootstrap, recovery, or non-reachable. Please retry the operation at a later time..",
    "query": "CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `List2_index` ON `List2` ;"
  }
]
```

Comment: @francisco i tried that, its not working

Comment: what version of Couchbase Server? what is the operating system?

Comment: @VarunPandey Looks like you do not have the indexing service on your couchbase cluster that is needed for creating the index. https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/services-and-indexes/services/index-service.html